# Deploying applications in Jetty (as a former Tomcat user)

Tags: ubuntu, java, web-applications, jetty, gwt

I'm trying to deploy a GWT app with Jetty. I have a folder with both static content and servlets (including web.xml and java class files). In Tomcat I was able to simply move this folder into the webapps directory, and `http://host:port/AppName/static.html` would point to the static page in that folder. Jetty gives me a `404` when I try this. I assume there's something I need to add to the `jetty.xml` file, but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what I need to do from the documentation provided. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

I'm running Jetty 5.1.14 installed from the Ubuntu 8.04 universe repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried building a war out of the directory? And then copying the package into '/usr/share/jetty/webapps' - directory.

Eg.

```
jar cvf MyApp.war -C MyApp/ .
sudo cp MyApp.war /usr/share/jetty/webapps/
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works! I feel so stupid for not trying that earlier. I was able to just copy the directory in Tomcat though, so I thought Jetty would allow me to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Jetty Documentation, specially the examples in the newbie guide and the WebAppDeployer explanation, you should be able to configure your webapp as expected.

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Newbie+Guide+to+Jetty

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20150509131131/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Newbie+Guide+to+Jetty